# Window scroll event to check if the bottom of page is reached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm implementing infinite scroll in my React app and, in order to accomplish that, I am following the instructions from this splendid blog post: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/build-an-infinite-scroll-component-in-react-using-react-hooks

However, there is one part that I find not clear.

Following snippet of code checks if the bottom of the page is reached.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  function handleScroll() {
    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) return;
    console.log('Fetch more list items!');
  }
```

Why inside `useEffect()` both `window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)` and `return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)` are needed? The event is added and then removed?

Comment: The useEffect hook is built in a way that if we return a function within the method, this function will execute when the component gets disassociated. This is very useful because we can use it to remove unnecessary behavior or prevent memory leaking issues.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of a `useEffect` should be a function to be used when the component is unMounted.

You don't want that event handler to stay attached when the component isn't on the screen anymore!

Don't worry, that arrow function that is being returned is not going to be executed straight away - only when the component is unMounted

[here it is in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

Comment: That's a perfect explanation! Many thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

It is because `useEffect`

```
return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

using `return` signifies `componentWillUnMount` in class based or stateful component.

`window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);`
using inside the `useEffect` is to assure component has been mounted and then we are adding scrollEvent.

Comment: Got it! Thank you